# How to effectively organize scripts so they can be put under version control?

Tags: linux, git, bash, version-control

I have an ever growing list of scripts from simple one liners in bash to more complex python scripts. 
Currently I source the one liners from a `~/.bash_functions` file, while I put the more complex scripts into `/usr/local/bin`.

I would like to put all my scripts under version control so that they are easily portable to different machines. 
Since not only my custom scripts reside under `usr/local/bin`, but also those of other appliactions, could I simply create a subdirectory, e.g. like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/scripts/
                      |-python
                      |-ruby
                      |-bash
```

and then just create a git repo out of said scripts folder? 
Or is there a better, canonical way to actually organizing and versioning scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would install them in `~/bin` and add that to your `$PATH`. You can then source control *your* bin directory as you wish.